# Dynamic content of .httacces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there any way to have .htaccess's content dynamically generated by itself?

Something like declaring a script language (ex: Python, Perl, PHP, etc) to be called to "interpret" the .htaccess and dump the output; very much like CGI.

I would like deploy a web application on different locations and I want to leave .htaccess untouched (as source) and load some local setting (inside .htaccess) and in the end to have a .htaccess configured for that location.

**More details**

To put it in another words. I want to know if .htaccess can be written and interpreted in Python, Perl or any other scripting language.

So the **.htaccess** should be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print('<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>');
....other code
print('</IfModule>')
```

Comment: You could create it as part of an "installation" process using another langauge. However, you could also build the necessassary _conditions_ into the `.htaccess` file itself so that it works in multiple environments. What exactly are you trying to do? What are the differences in the environments you are trying to support?

Comment: Certainly that is possible. Actually many CMS systems for example do exactly that. In the end a configuration file is a simple text file (".htaccess" files are _distributed configuration files_ ). And certainly text files can easily be written by an automatic process. If that is a good idea is another thing... If such resources are writable by the using process itself you open pandora's box for an ocean of possible attacks. You should always prefer to get along without such files at all. Either use the static configuration or a routing script.

Comment: @MrWhite Mainly I need to have different .htaccess content for example for dev box and for real website. I simply do not want to have to change the .htaccess every time I do a deploy.

Comment: You should try to keep your development setup as close as possible to the production setup for obvious reasons. There should not be any changes required at all. If you really cannot get around that using such files then consider making the creation of that configuration file part of your distribution pipeline.

Comment: There are many ways to do this in the `.htaccess` file itself - it does not necessarily need to be "dynamically generated". But it can depend on exactly what you are trying to do and the environment(s) it is being installed on. You could, for instance, define a server var on your "dev box" and check for this in `.htaccess` (`<IfDefine>`) setting various options, applying various rules based on whether this server var is set or not. Or base this conditonal on the hostname through which you access the site? Or configure the rules themselves to be sufficiently dynamic to match the server config?